# Django: How to deal with model subclassing and IntegrityErros?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have this in my `models.py`

```
class Page(models.Model)
    #fields

class News(Page)
    #no fields

class NewsComment(models.Model)
    news = models.Foreignkey(news)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    comment = models.TextField()
```

Every time I am trying this:

`page = get_object_or_404(News, id=page_id)`

and then

`comment, created = NewsComment.objects.get_or_create(news=page, name=name, email=email, comment=text)`

I get this error:

`(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (myproject_db.main_newscomment, CONSTRAINT news_id_refs_page_ptr_id_5a5b8a6204eece43 FOREIGN KEY (news_id) REFERENCES main_news (page_ptr_id))')`

What am I doing wrong?

(PS: I am using MySQL with InnoDB storage engine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the News model has no fields you should implement the inheritance using [a proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). It will lead to much simpler database schema, and much simpler and faster (!) queries. It will also eliminate most problems dealing with how model inheritance is implemented on the database level.

```
class Page(models.Model)
    #fields

class News(Page)
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes you suggest and it seems I can't migrate. It stops at this point: Running migrations for main:
 - Migrating forwards to 0004_auto__del_news__chg_field_newscomment_news.
 > main:0004_auto__del_news__chg_field_newscomment_news
   = SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; []
   = SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; []
   = DROP TABLE `main_news` CASCADE; []
   - no dry run output for alter_column() due to dynamic DDL, sorry
   = SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; []
   = DROP TABLE `main_news` CASCADE; []

Comment: It tries to DROP the database table for News model, as it's no longer needed. I don't know what's wrong, since what you pasted doesn't seem like an error. You may try emptying all tables manually. If you are the only person working on the project you can even just delete the migrations and start from scratch, generating the initial migration.